# Most efficient way to delete data

Tags: mysql

I am working on a forum system and I need to delete all topics and posts from a particular forum.

There is a `posts` table that holds all the posts. Each post has `topic_id` field which is the ID of the topic to which it belongs. The topics reside in `topics` table and each topic has `forum_id` field which is the ID of the forum it belongs to.

So now when I decide to delete forum with ID `1`, how would I go about deleting all topics and posts from this forum as well?

Comment: Write a SQL `DELETE` query.

Comment: Yes, but how would that query look like? Am able to write simple DELTE queries, but this one looks a bit complicated, given the nested structure...

Comment: You should not try to delete from different tables in one query. Do multiple deletes in a transaction instead. If you get stuck, post your query and describe your problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you entirely want to delete the post? shouldn't you archive all your posts and maybe when they older than 6 months delete them.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked into the [MySQL documentation on `DELETE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I recommend you take a good look at your data structure: If you use foreign key constraints of the `ON DELETE CASCADE` flavour, your sub-deletes will automatically be done for you - and this just one of the advantages you get.

If for some reasons you can't or don't want to employ such constraints, start by taking a look at how you would select the relvant topics and posts. This should give you quite a good start.

In your particular example something like

```
DELETE FROM posts
WHERE topic_id IN (
     SELECT id FROM topics WHERE forum_id=[id-to-delete]
  )
```

and then

```
DELETE FROM topics WHERE forum_id=[id-to-delete]
```

should do the trick.

Please understand, that I don't recommend that. Use data consistency tools for data consistency.

Answer (score 0):

this sql should delete all posts related to the forum 1. the topics would still be in the db and would have to be deleted additionally.
Haven't tested the sql, just try it out :)

```
DELETE FROM
    posts
WHERE 
    topic_id
IN (
    SELECT 
        topic_id
    FROM
        topics
    WHERE
        forum_id = 1
)
```